How to run a C++ Visual Studio project on a Windows nanoserver Docker Container?
First of all, I'm truly sorry if this is a stupid question. I'm running out of time and I can't seem to find any answers online. I'm new to Docker and I'm trying to run my compiled Visual Studio project on a nanoserver container.
This is my Dockerfile:
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver:ltsc2019

WORKDIR C:\\app

COPY . C:\\app\\

CMD ["C:\\app\\RaftAlgorithm.exe"]

When running the exe file inside the container, it doesn't seem to do anything, like so:
C:\app\>RaftAlgorithm.exe

C:\app\>

When running the exe outside of the container, it works great (it runs in a loop and prints stuff from time to time).
To check if the problem is with the exe, I tried running a different project in the container and it didn't run as well. What did I do wrong and why doesn't the exe run? Do I need to recompile the project to fit Windows nanoserver even though I compiled the project in Windows? If so, how?
I also tried running it on Windows servercore as ChatGPT told me it's probably a dependency problem that should be resolved on servercore. It didn't work.
Update:
Used dumpbin to find project dependencies. Copied listed dlls to container and rebuilt the project as release. This worked!

Have you tried finding out what your executable is dependent on, and if those dependencies are available in your docker container? The obvious candidates for this would be the C and C++ runtimes.

I made sure the C and C++ runtimes are available in my container, but it still doesn't work. Is there a way for me to find out what dependencies are required by my project and aren't available in nanoserver as default, or should I just go through each file in my project and make sure every imported library is available in the container?

In the old days I would have used a tool called Dependency Walker, but I'm told it's no longer reliable. But if you google Window dependency checker I'm sure you can find a suitable replacement.

This tool claims to have fixed the problems of dependency walker and modern OSs: https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies
